# Does a MASER beam stay un-dispersed like that of a laser?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, dispersion, microwaves, laser-interaction

We know that a laser beam has a very low dispersion rate.  Does the same apply for a MASER (Microwave Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation) beam?